# Designing a class that varies by metadata

Tags: oop

I have a scenario to create the common class definition. I have a class name called as `Product` and product may have product details like Name, Brand, cost etc...

But metadata about the product may change like `Pen - May have Color,Type, Ink` and `Pencil - May have Color, WithEraser,Size` etc...

I have to get these details thrught the WCF service. So I have to create Request object to hold the information to be carried forward to server.

I don't like to include the pen related metadata info to the client if pencil is asked and vice versa.

I am thinking of Create Interface for each productMetadata like

Pen - Color, type and Ink 
Pencil - Color, Size and WithEraser,

I want to to implement them in the individual classes and also Common product MetaData classes. Based on the type of product I will create a new object and use it.

Is there any other perfect solution to solve this.

Comment: An important question is, do you want the `Pen` to be strongly typed or not? Trying to get `WithEraser` from a `Pen` object is a runtime error or compile time error?

Comment: Its strongly typed...

Comment: I've done similar things with Qt in C++. But that have heavy dependency on Qt's QObject class and Meta Object Compiler. I'm not sure if it'll be useful to you but I'll share my code with you.

Comment: Something related: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#details